# Elementor widget that opens up as a full screen video on click

Tags: javascript, css, elementor

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('fullscreen-button');
    var videoWrapper = document.querySelector('.video-wrapper');
    var video = videoWrapper.querySelector('video');
    var closeButton = document.getElementById('close-button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      videoWrapper.style.display = 'block';

      if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
    });

    closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (document.fullscreenElement) {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
      } else {
        videoWrapper.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.video-button-container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    
    
  }

  #fullscreen-button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .video-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: none;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  .video-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  #close-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10000;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="video-button-container">
  <button id="fullscreen-button">Play Video</button>
  <div class="video-wrapper">
    <i id="close-button" class="fas fa-times"></i>
    <video class="video-content" controls autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://www.pexels.com/video/a-grayscale-video-of-snow-covered-mountains-14916652/" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make an Elementor widget as a button that opens up as a full screen video on click and it is opening up as a full screen video but I couldn't make the close toggle appear on the full screen video, we have to click on minimise option to make the close toggle visible
Any suggestions/edits to the below code to make the close icon appear on full screen video .